# Path variables in cabal configuration file

Tags: windows, haskell, configuration-files, cabal

On Windows, I want to change the default per-user installation directories of `cabal`. The relevant part of the `config` file is:

```
install-dirs user
  prefix: C:\path\to\my\folder
  -- bindir: $prefix\bin
  -- libdir: $prefix
  -- libsubdir: $abi\$libname
  -- libexecdir: $prefix\$libname
  -- datadir: $prefix
  -- datasubdir: $abi\$pkgid
  -- docdir: $datadir\doc\$abi\$pkgid
  -- htmldir: $docdir\html
  -- haddockdir: $htmldir
  -- sysconfdir: $prefix\etc
```

What are `$abi` and `$pkgid` ? They are not defined in the `config` file. Does `cabal` have a default value for these variables (which ones) ? How/where can I define them ?

#### Edit

@Sibi's answer is perfect. Just to complete the information, I also modified these parameters:

```
remote-repo-cache: C:\path\to\my\folder\packages
logs-dir: C:\path\to\my\folder\logs
world-file: C:\path\to\my\folder\world
build-summary: C:\path\to\my\folder\logs\build.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer [here](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.14/Cabal-1.24.2.0/Distribution-Simple-InstallDirs.html#t:PathTemplateVariable) to get more details on them.

`$abi` corresponds to `AbiVar` type.

`$pkgid` corresponds to `PkgIdVar` type.

They are not defined in the config file. They will be generated by Cabal during the build steps depending on your architecture etc. You can [see this guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#installation-paths) to understand the installation paths.

For my Linux system, their values are:

`$abi` is x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3

`$pkgid` refers to package name along with it's version. Example: `array-1.2.3.4`

But if you want to change the location, my advise would be to just change the `prefix` path as that is the root installation folder. Everything else will be relative to that.

Comment: Ok thanks, so there are default values if I understand well. It doesn't seem that everything is relative to `prefix`, for example `libsubdir: $abi\$libname`. Or is `libsubdir` automatically a subdirectory of `libdir` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent According to the code, yes. See the function `appendSubdirs` in the module `InstallDirs.hs` to see why. The best way to understand this and the related things IMO, is to just see the code. :)

Comment: Thank you. It works fine, but I have another point. The package database (packages.conf.d) goes to `%APPDATA%/ghc` (`%APPDATA%` is the default path for installation, this is like `~` on Linux I think). Do you know how to change that ? I tried the `package-db` option, unsuccessfully.

Comment: I'm still interested if you have an idea but I have a workaround. I automatically use a sandbox using the environment variable [CABAL_SANDBOX_CONFIG](https://ro-che.info/articles/2014-03-05-cabal-sandbox-tips). Then everything is installed in this sandbox, regardless of the current directory. This is not very convenient if I want to use a local sandbox: I have to do `cabal --sandbox-config-file=cabal.sandbox.config sandbox init` after creating by hand an empty  `cabal.sandbox.config` file in the current directory. Then I also use the option `--sandbox-config-file` for `cabal install`.